# Checking which code uses permissions

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I've recently changed an app to target Marshmallow and as you know, I now need to handle the Marshmallow permissions model.

The app hasmany files and thousands of lines of code. Aside from the brute force way ie

*turn off permissions and use the app , noting where exceptions happen*

is there a more efficient way of finding out which lines of api calls request certain permissions so that they can be wrapped in a permission request?

Comment: i tried to figure it out same question some weeks ago, best what i found its to use aspectJ for android. But its not fast solution and maybe difficult, because u also need to make pointcuts for methods which need permissions.
Other way (not good one, but it will give to you time for wrapping) is set targetSdkVersion less then 23.

Answer (score 2):

There are some methods that will raise a lint error if they do not detect permission checks (for example location updates using Google Play Services.) To trigger that run Analyze > Inspect Code and look under the Android Lint Errors.

Other than that brute force is the only way. I had to do this for a project I was working on (also many many thousands of lines of code). I suggest monitoring Logcat for errors and hitting the app hard. Be careful though... if you catch the errors in code then they may not appear in logcat so you'll have to make sure the app functionality is as expected.

But, it's not as hard as it sounds. If take a moment to review your app and the potential locations where permissions are required you'll find that its pretty straight forward. Review this article to determine what permissions you'll need http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en